# Struts2 Action fields are not being filled after submitting the form

Tags: struts2

We have issue in struts2 action sometimes after submitting the form the fields come as null
even though we have setters for these fields, and this issue happening some times after restarting the server,
this issue happens rarely and to solve it we need to restart the server again

Comment: There’s nothing here anyone can use to help. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.